# Hook in to add new post link wp admin?

Tags: posts, wp-admin, multi-language, plugin-wpml

How can i customize the **Add new post** link or how can i add my custom parameter in add new post link like **http://www.test.localhost/wp-admin/post-new.php** looks like **http://www.test/wp-admin/post-new.php?lang=fr**

I have customized  the links in menu by

```
global $menu, $submenu;
$submenu['edit.php'][10][2]='post-new.php?lang='.ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
```

But what i want to hook all the links`(post-new.php?lang='')` where ever it appears in the admin panel

Comment: I'd add a bit more code so people can see how you're applying that code.